# Book on .Net Serialization?

Tags: .net, serialization

Can anyone please recomend me a book on >net Serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered "Pro .NET 2.0 XML", by Bipin Joshi?

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41SMA4j5eiL._BO2,204,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,35,-76_AA240_SH20_OU02_.jpg](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-NET-Experts-Voice-Net/dp/1590598253/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_a)